# update data without refresh page in script google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, google-maps

i have a problem with update data without refresh page. 
I use CodeIgniter to develop my sistem.

i have button "update waktu" in info windows each point(marker) on google maps.

this is pick info window

[pick info windows button "update waktu"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvKlY.png)

this is my code to view google maps

```
var lokasi_cust = [<?php       
            foreach($all_cust as $coord){
            echo'
            ["<ul class=\"list-group\">"+
            "<li class=\"list-group-item\"><b><center>Info Customer</b></center></li>"+ 
            "<li class=\"list-group-item\">Nomor : '.$coord->id.'</li>"+    
            "<li class=\"list-group-item\">Nama Tempat : '.$coord->nama_tempat.'</li>"+     
            "<li class=\"list-group-item\">Alamat : '.$coord->nama_jalan.', No '.$coord->no_rumah.', <br>'.$coord->kelurahan.', '.$coord->kecamatan.', '.$coord->kota.'</li>"+
            "<li class=\"list-group-item\"><pre>Estimasi jarak: '.$coord->jarak.', <br>Estimasi waktu: '.$coord->waktu.'</pre></li>"+
            "<li class=\"list-group-item\"><pre><a href=editwaktu?id='.$coord->id.'&&lat='.$coord->lat.'&&lng='.$coord->lng.'>Update Waktu</a></pre></li>"+
            "</ul>",'.$coord->lat.', '.$coord->lng.'],';
            }
            ?>        
            ];                      

            //Marker untuk lokasi customer
            var marker_cust, y;

            for (y = 0; y < lokasi_cust.length; y++) {  
            marker_cust = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lokasi_cust[y][1], lokasi_cust[y][2]),
            map: map,
            icon:'<?php echo base_url();?>assets/icon/cust.png'
            });

            //Info Window untuk marker customer
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker_cust, 'click', (function(marker_cust, y) {
            return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(lokasi_cust[y][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker_cust);
            }
            })(marker_cust, y));    
            markers.push(marker_cust);
            }       

            function showmarker(id,latx,lngy){
            $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#map-header").offset().top
            }, 1000);       

            var coord = new google.maps.LatLng(latx, lngy);
            map.setCenter(coord);   

            google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id], 'click');
            }
```

and this is my code when button "update waktu" presssed :

```
function editwaktu()
{
    $id_cust=(int)$_GET['id'];
    $lat_cust=$_GET['lat'];
    $lng_cust=$_GET['lng'];

    $urlDistanceMatrix = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=-7.7782792,110.3651149&destinations=$lat_cust,$lng_cust&mode=driving&departure_time=now&traffic_model=pessimistic&avoid=highways&key=KEY";
    $jsonUrlDistanceMatrix = file_get_contents($urlDistanceMatrix, false);
    $jsonDistanceMatrix = json_decode($jsonUrlDistanceMatrix, true);
    $waktu = $jsonDistanceMatrix['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration_in_traffic']['text'];

    $insert = array();
    $insert['waktu'] = $waktu;

    $this->bidashboard_model->update_waktu($insert, $id_cust);}
```

i want when button "update waktu" pressed info windows will update data "estimasi waktu" without refresh page. please help me..
thankyou...